# Getting error while try run Emulator in Ubuntu system Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Getting errors:

> **Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_6P_API_28], use
>    -list-avds to see valid list.**
>
> **Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1**

Virtualisation is on and lib64stdc++6:i386 is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved. 
The problem occur due to android studio is opening in **sudo mode**.